# My pc gives me freeze frames, but not when TaskManager is active

Tags: freeze, task-manager

I have a strange problem, and I dont know the cause. but i have a simple solution.

I use my PC primarily to do 3D rendering, so it's quite good (Core i7, 8GB, 650GTX, Windows7-64bit, etc.).

But, i my PC stalls for a moment at regular basis (it's UI is unresponsive for maybe a second). During that time if I have video running, video WILL PLAY without any problems. It's really bugging me, and i don't know why is this happening.

Accidentally, I found a solution, that is not really a solution. If i open Task Manager when I boot up my computer, there is no freezing. As if Task Manager refreshes UI or something more frequently than it wound normally happen.

Software that i use: Adobe After Effects, MAXSON Cinema 4D, etc.

Has anyone have case like this. Maybe it's hardware related, maybe it's a trifle of some sort, but i'am going crazy...

Any insight would me much appreciated.

EDIT:

After Darth Android's answer I realized that I forgot to mention that I use WD VelociRaptor 500 GB for my system drive. I did the test with Crystal Disk Info and with WD Win Diagnostics but they did not find any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the health of your harddrives. Temporary system lockups can be caused by a dying harddrive, when data is requested and the harddrive takes several attempts at re-reading the data until it succeeds.

As to why the video keeps playing: Video playback is typically done with hardware acceleration / overlay these days, which means the graphics card, not the CPU is doing the video playback. The GPU will continue to play the video even if the system freezes as long as it has additional video data in its buffer. It too, will freeze after the 5-10 seconds of buffer are used up.